# Can't get wifi working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, wireless, wpa-supplicant

I've been digging through this but I can't seem to figure out why I can't get wifi working on my fresh install of 16.04 server. (And just for the record - it is **super** irritating that wifi works fine when installing, but doesn't after.) I'm using a Tenda W311U usb adapter for wifi.

I'm a bit of a newbie as far as networking goes, so bear with me. Also, sorry for not copying exact messages, I don't have an easy way to pull data off the machine.

I've found the correct name for my wireless interface and setup a .conf in /etc/network/interfaces.d for my wireless configuration.

Running `iwconfig` I see the name of my wireless interface but simply a message next to saying "no wireless extensions".

Running `lshw -class network` shows me my wireless interface as recognized but disabled.

I tried running `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i <wireless interface name> -c wpa.conf` where `wpa.conf` was generated by `wpa_passphrase`. This fails with a lot of "Operation not supported" messages, so I switched `-Dwext` to `-Dnl80211`. This then tells me that it "Could not configure driver mode" then "deinit ..." then "failed to initialize driver interface".

Anyone know how to resolve this? Or better yet - anyone know how to just pop the connection from the installer and put that in my system?

Comment: Can you please post the output of the `lsusb` command? I believe the Tenda W311U is a RaLink RT3070, but it would be good to confirm this. If so, then you might want to perform a `sudo modprobe rt2800usb` to enable the native kernel driver. But, one step at a time...

Comment: "Running lshw -class network shows me my wireless interface as recognized but disabled." We'd like to see the result of: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep rt2`